# Strong Customer Authentication (SCA) and taking payments without customer present

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, payment

> On September 14, 2019, a new regulation for authentication will be introduced in Europe. Known as Strong Customer Authentication (SCA), this regulation will apply to online payments within the European Economic Area (EEA) where the cardholder’s bank and the business’s payment provider are both in the EEA. Some businesses outside of Europe may also be impacted depending on how European issuers implement the new authentication rules.
>
> SCA requires that businesses use two independent authentication elements to verify payments. Transactions that don’t meet these new authentication requirements or qualify for any exemption may be declined starting September 14, 2019. 3D Secure 2—the new version of 3D Secure rolling out in 2019—will be the primary authentication method used to meet SCA requirements for card payments.

[Source](https://stripe.com/guides/strong-customer-authentication)

These new regulations mean that for certain purchases 3D secure (or equivalent) will be required when purchasing online.

My question is how will this affect purchases where the customer is not present, eg. over the phone. I would assume the customer would not be expected to give their verified by visa password over the phone. I have not been able to find information on this specifically.

Comment: Why do you think an “over the phones” payment is “online”?

Comment: @DaleM So in my circumstances, I am a web developer creating a web portal for a client which should be able to take payments over the phone. Currently, stripe, our payment providers, allows us to do this fine. When 3D secure is required, that may be a different story. That is why I care and why it is 'online'.